# How can I remove unsolicited posts/spam from my Facebook news feed?

Tags: facebook

I am currently being slammed with pages in my news feed that I haven't liked. They are liked, supposedly, by one or more of my friends. The posts are not showing which of my friends like the pages and I haven't found out where to find the list of my friends who like the pages.

Also the arrow on the right hand side of the post that allows me to hide and report as spam isn't with the posts. I am having to go to their pages to report as spam. I don't think that I should be subjected to these unwanted and unsolicited posts.

How can I get rid of them and prevent them from showing up?

Answer (score 1):

These posts that you are taking about are "Sponsored" posts, which have only recently started to surface around Facebook.

They can be removed, like any other post:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To preemptively stop them showing up, there's a set it and forget it method, which means you don't have to keep manually hiding those posts.

Simply install the safe and free  **FB Purity** browser extension, and it will automatically hide all the ads on Facebook. You can get it via http://www.fbpurity.com